# Laravel Middleware getting error 'Too few arguments to function'

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm trying to make an onboarding section for my website. But while trying to implement my middleware I get the following error.

[image: Error Message]

I`m trying to do my onboarding process by assigning a different onboarding value each time the user completes a section of the onboarding process. Such that they start the process with an onboarded value of 0 and once all steps are completed there onboarded value will be 4.  Below you can see my current middleware and web.php attempts.

Middleware :

```
class OnBoarding
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, User $user)
    {
        if (! Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        return $next($request);
        if (Auth::user()->onboarded == 0) {
            return redirect()->route('employment.index', $user);
        }
        return $next($request);
        if (Auth::user()->onboarded == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('qualificationsAndCertifications.index', $user);
        }
        return $next($request);
        if (Auth::user()->onboarded == 2) {
            return redirect()->route('extraDocs.index', $user);
        }
        return $next($request);
        if (Auth::user()->onboarded == 3) {
            return redirect()->route('additionalInformation.index', $user);
        }
        return $next($request);
        if (Auth::user()->onboarded == 4) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
        }
        return $next($request);

    }
}
```

Web.php :

```
Route::middleware('auth','verified','onboarded')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/onboarding/employment/{user}', [UserController::class , 'employment'])- >name('employment.index');

    Route::get('/onboarding/additional-information/{user}', [UserController::class , 'additionalInformation'])->name('additionalInformation.index');

    Route::get('/onboarding/certification/{user}', [UserController::class , 'qualificationsAndCertifications'])
    ->name('qualificationsAndCertifications.index');

    Route::get('/onboarding/certification/extra/{user}', [UserController::class , 'extraDocs'])->name('extraDocs.index');
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but this is my first time touching middleware in PHP so assume I'm making a really stupid mistake and therefore any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you try to remove param `$user` from handle method, does it help?

Comment: I don't get the error message anymore but the middleware doesn't work. Like I can navigate to any page I want.

Comment: Remove `User $user` and write down `$user = Auth::user()`

Comment: It's because after first if() statement you are returning next request, so all other conditions won't be checked

Comment: I also advise you to use switch case in this method

Comment: @StewieSWS if I remove the return $next($request); and the $user from the middleware.,  I then get the error Missing parameter: user

Comment: @BhargavChudasama if I do that I get the following error Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: Where did you put it @JacPhillipps? Inside function params?

Comment: yes like this, Is that not the correct use of it ? `public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next,$user = Auth::user())`

Comment: Well you should put it inside function, not in its parameters

Comment: Sorry yeah being thick Ill try that now

Comment: I now get the following error This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.

Comment: You need to check if current route is not the one you want to redirect user to. If it is, then return `$next($request) `. I suggest you to put all redirect routes inside associative array where key is the value of onboarded column. Then check if current route is correct and based on that redirect or return the request

Answer (score 0):

Why ara so many `return $next($request);` on handle

// For a route with the following URI: profile/{id}

```
return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes